# Design Patterns: Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software

Tags: java, c++, design-patterns

Before diving into the book Design Patterns (the gang of four) I wanted to ask a general question...

The Introduction to this book mentions that it will use C++ for primary code examples, have any of you Java experts read this book, and will I easily be able to relate, and even more importantly, implement the design patterns in Java?

I know this is a somewhat vague question, but I do not want to waste any of my time if this book really is geared more towards the C++ programmer.

I look forward to your opinions!

Comment: Consider what a pattern is.

Comment: There is a big `it depends on you`. Read the pattern, look at the examples, then you can google for examples of that particular pattern if you can't quite underestand it by looking at the C++ code. I believe you can understand if you know basic C++ and basic Java.

Comment: I think Heads First series tackles the patterns in Java. Also even if that is not the case, I will recommend that you start with Heads first series. The GoF book is a tough one for beginners (assuming that you are a beginner)

Comment: @NotAgain The Head First Design Patterns is, indeed, written in Java

Comment: I'm not a beginner, I'm also OCJP certified.

Comment: In that case the GoF book is good, although being not a beginner and OCJP then many of the patterns will be very familiar.

Comment: sorry but, what is OCJP certified?

Comment: "Will I easily be able to relate, and even more importantly, implement the design patterns in Java?" <- Absolutely, yes.

Comment: I think there are better patterns books aimed directly at Java if that is your specific goal.  Personally, for all its acclaim - and it deserves more than a little for being something of a breakthrough tome - I never found GoF that great a book.

Comment: @omainegra - try using google

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That book will hardly ever be a waste of time. And it can easily translate to any object oriented language. For example: I found my Python designs improved because of the book, even though design patterns in Python are implemented in significantly different manners.

What the book provided me (and is an explicit objective of the whole concept) is language to articulate my intents to me and to others. It is easier to think or say "this composite could be traversed by visitors" than to articulate that you would like a decoupled set of functionality conditionally applied to elements of a nested data structure.

Now: beware of the pattern bug.

Not everything HAS to be a pattern, and some times I wasted a tremendous amount of time trying to "patternize" perfectly working software.

So, I'll conclude: read it, learn it, use it, but don't abuse it.

Comment: Sounds good, I will read and study it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No trouble at all, and the examples do not use a C++ too complicated.

The main problem I found is that some examples are written for Smalltalk, and those are harder to understand (if you do not know Smalltalk) and more difficult to translate to Java.

For example, in the `Decorator` pattern a variation is that you call a method ("message" in Smalltalk) in the decorator and, if it does not define such method, changes the default to send/delegate that method/message to the decorated object.